# how to make last focused filed should be focused after refresh html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to focus the last edited(*focused*) element to be **focus** after refresh the page. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<input id="first"><br>
<input id="second"><br>
<input id="third"><br>
<input id="four"><br>
<input id="five"><br>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you do to let the page know a file has been edited?

Comment: Try to use cookies or localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `localStorage` and `onfocus` events:

```
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var active = localStorage.getItem("myTestApp");
            if (active) {
                e = document.getElementById(active).focus();
                console.log('Focused to ' + active);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <input id="first" onfocus="localStorage.setItem('myTestApp','first')"/><br>
    <input id="second" onfocus="localStorage.setItem('myTestApp','second')"/><br>
    <input id="third" onfocus="localStorage.setItem('myTestApp','third')"/><br>
    <input id="four" onfocus="localStorage.setItem('myTestApp','four')"/><br>
    <input id="five" onfocus="localStorage.setItem('myTestApp','five')"/><br>
</body>
```

It has been tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.